# GRASS in QGIS - ' Cannot read raster map region' (running r.lake.xy)

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-2.18, qgis-grass-plugin

I want to use the GRASS function `r.lake.xy` on a DEM that I have.

- I load the DEM raster into QGIS, it is not georeferenced. Then I create a New Mapset. I set Projection `Not defined`. I either leave the Default GRASS Region, or set it to `90/-90/180/-180` (I've tried both). I'm told my Mapset (named DEM5) is successfuly created.
- I open GRASS tools and select `r.lake.xy`.
- The first strange thing is the dropdown for `Name of input elevation raster map` doesn't allow me to select either of the options ('DEM5' or 'Permanent'). So I type in DEM5.
- I type in Seed point coordinates and Water level and name my output file.
- I click run but I'm given the error message: `Cannot read raster map region - pathname: Unable to open header file for raster map DEM5@DEM5`.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your procedure is somewhat backwards.

- First you create the mapset.
- Then you load the DEM into that mapset (r.in.gdal command).
- Then run the r.lake command.

BTW, working in an undefined projection is certainly going to **lead you into trouble**. What is the coordinate reference system of your DEM? You should (must?) begin by creating a location that matches that CRS, then start a new mapset inside that location, and continue from there.