# Error while trying to use GRASS GIS' r.reclass module

Tags: grass-gis, reclassify

I'm not sure I understand how to use [`r.reclass`](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/r.reclass.html) in GRASS.

Can somebody go through what the inputs should be or direct me to a tutorial (I've looked...) for the current version? I get an error when I try to use it, and I think it's just because my text inputs are wrong or something like that

EDIT:
My inputs were:

**Name of raster to be reclassified**

grdn36w104_13 [a DEM from the USGS]

**File containing reclass rules**

(a .txt file with the text)

```
 1525 thru 3110 = 1
    0 thru 1524 = NULL
    3111 thru 5000  = NULL
```

**Name for raster output map**

test

The error message was:

[image]

Followed by "Cannot get region map of grdn36w104_13@Elevation_Data", then "Cannot get input region"

Comment: Did you set the computational region? Please see https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Computational_region

Comment: In my limited knowledge, I'm having a hard time understanding how this is relevant to what I'm doing, i.e. the wiki page has information but nothing actionable that I can find for my situation

Comment: "Absolute data is different. Here the challenge is to redistribute a finite amount of something into the new cells. It is not an issue of interpolation, but an issue of reassigning data from one partition into another."  This seems like the most relevant section, but from what I've read about r.reclass it is just reassigning raster values (actually mapping groups of values to other values, not even creating a new raster to save disk space), not changing the resolution

Comment: What I'm trying to say is 'What should I do here?'. If this computational region stuff is the issue what do I do? This isn't really talked about in the wiki

Comment: 1st) can you view the map you are trying to reclassify? 2nd) GRASS operates always inside the defined computational region. If the extent of the map in question is outside the defined computational region, nothing can/will happen. I remember that there is the possibility to actually see GRASS' computational region withing from QGIS. It's been some time I've last used it.

Comment: The entire raster was loaded and visible. I just double checked

Comment: There are two "region"-relevant screenshots in the above linked wiki page. Here also two more useful links: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/77648/5256 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/241891/5256, I believe. Essentialy, in working with GRASS-GIS, you need to 1) create a Location with the spatial reference system of your data in question, 2) import your data in the PERMANENT or another custom Mapset, 3) match the computational region to the map of interest, 4) create the reclassification rules file (which, above, appears to be correct), and 5) run `r.reclassify`.

Comment: I feel ok about 3, 4 and 5, and I think I did 1 when I started GRASS for the first time (I chose N. America, unless this was for something else). I never imported my data, I'll look into that

Comment: Indeed, that was the issue. Worked great once I imported the raster. Thanks for walking me through that!

Comment: Happy it works. Maybe writing an answer and accepting it would be meaningful, so this does not look like an open question.

Comment: I was going to suggest you write an answer and I'll accept it, so you can get credit for answering my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach to work with GRASS GIS' [r.reclass](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/r.reclass.html) module is:

1. create a [Location](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/helptext.html#selecting-the-location-(a-project)) based on the spatial reference system of the data in question
2. import the data in question in the [PERMANENT](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/helptext.html#the-role-of-the-permanent-mapset) or another custom [Mapset](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/helptext.html#creating-and-maintaining-mapsets)
3. set the [computational region](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Computational_region) to match the extent of the data in question
4. create the [reclassification rules](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/r.reclass.html#reclass-rules) file--the rules posted in the question appear to be correct
5. run `r.reclass`

Related Q&As

- https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/77648/5256
- https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/241891/5256